# printing with type long

Tags: c, algorithm

I'm working on my school project form data structure and I'm having a problem with the type long. 
I want to design a small project like a university registration system.
First the person get to chose if he want to register or exit. 
If he want to register then he will enter his name and gpa to select the major that is available based on his gpa and the system will generate an id automatically.

**The problem is the id is not incremented correctly.**

Additional info:
I'm using doubly linked list structure

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<string.h>
struct student{
    char name[30];
    int GPA;
    unsigned long ID;
    char colloege[100];
    student *next, *prev;
};
student *stu, *cur, *head, *tail;
void insertfront();
void displaylist(){
    unsigned long id=214000000;
    cur=head;
    printf(" ");
    if(cur==NULL)
        printf(" ");
    else
        while(cur!=NULL){
            printf("Name:%s\t",cur->name);
            printf("ID:%d\t",cur->ID=id++);
            printf("GPA:%d\t",cur->GPA);
            printf("Colloege of:%s\t",cur->colloege);
            printf("\n");
            cur=cur->next;
        }
    }

void main(){
    clrscr();
    int x;
    printf("\n\t\t\t\t******* King Faisal University *********\n");
    while(x!=2){
        printf("\n press 1 to insert your information ,press 2 to exit\n");
        scanf("%d",&x);
        insertfront();
        displaylist();
    }

    stu=NULL;
    cur=NULL;
    head=NULL;
    tail=NULL;
    getch();
}

void insertfront(){
    int x,c;
    stu=(student*)malloc(sizeof(student));
    fflush(stdin);
    printf("Enter your name:\n");
    scanf("%[^\n]%*c",stu->name);
    printf("Enter your GPA:\n");
    scanf("%ul",&stu->GPA);
    printf("\n Available Colloeges\n");

    if(stu->GPA>=85)
    {
        printf("1.Colloege of Medicine\n 2.Colloege of Engenering\n 3.Colloege of Computer Science\n 4.Colloege of Business\n 5.Colloege of Art\n");
        printf("Enter the colloege number \n");
        scanf("%d",&c);
        switch(c){
            case 1:  strcpy(stu->colloege,"Medicien");break;
            case 2:  strcpy(stu->colloege,"Engenering");break;
            case 3:  strcpy(stu->colloege,"Computer Science");break;
            case 4:  strcpy(stu->colloege,"Business");break;
            case 5: strcpy(stu->colloege,"Art");break;
        }
    }
    else if(stu->GPA>=75)
    {
        printf("1.Colloege of Computer Science\n 2.Colloege of Business\n 3.Colloege of Art\n");
        printf("Enter the colloege number\n");
        scanf("%d",&c);
        switch(c){
            case 1:  strcpy(stu->colloege,"Computer Science");break;
            case 2:  strcpy(stu->colloege,"Business");break;
            case 3: strcpy(stu->colloege,"Art");break;
        }
    }
    else
        strcpy(stu->colloege,"Art");
    if(head==NULL)
    {
        stu->next=NULL;
        stu->prev=NULL;
        head=stu;
        tail=stu;
    }
    else
    {
        stu->next=head;
        stu->prev=NULL;
        head->prev=stu;
        head=stu;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate on the problems you are having. Do you have build errors? Run-time errors or crashes? Unexpected results? You might want to [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and also how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Then finally, you should learn how to format your code to make it readable, with indentation.

Comment: Are you using a C++ compiler? your code is invalid C (the struct name does not go into global scope automatically in C)! For your own sanity use a C compiler for C code :-)

Comment: Setting record ID while printing it is pure evil.

Comment: @pmg i'm using turbo C++ actually what do recommend ?

Comment: @NajlaAlKroud: I recommend a C compiler for C code (and a C++ compiler for C++ code). If you're on Windows hopefully you can use a [free version of Microsoft Visual Studio](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/visual-studio-express-vs.aspx) properly configured for C. Anyway, google for C compilers, try a few and choose the one you like best.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg i'm not having any errors but the output is not coming out correctly with the id instead of printing 21400001and so on it prints a random value. Sorry for any inconvenience i'm just a bigger and still learning. Thank you for your feedback.

Comment: @pmg okay Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are using an incorrect conversion in your program

```
printf("ID:%d\t",cur->ID=id++);
// cur->ID is of type unsigned long
// %d is used for values of type int
```

To print a value of type `long` you need to use `"%ld"` in the `printf()` conversion

```
long longvalue = 42;
printf("%ld\n", lonvgalue);
```

To print a value of type `unsigned long` you need to use `"%lu"` in the `printf()` conversion

```
unsigned long ulongvalue = 42;
printf("%lu\n", ulongvalue);
```

Comment: it worked but now i'm facing another problem :( Every time i enter a new person the id of the pervious person is incremented :/

Comment: You have to pay attention to where you are doing the increment. See [Klas's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33913766/25324).

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the format specifier being wrong, you have a problem with assigning ID:s.

Your code assigns new ID:s every time you display the list.

I would generate the ID only once for each student record, when the record is created.

So add this in `insertfront`:

```
stu->ID=id++;
```

and change the printing in `displaylist` to:

```
printf("ID:%lu\t",cur->ID);
```

and move the declaration of `id` either to global scope (outside of any function) or as a static variable inside `insertfront`:

```
static unsigned long id=214000000;
```

Comment: okay i did but now i'm getting a Warning that the id is assigned a value that is never used

Comment: Yeah, I've added to my answer that you need to move the declaration of `id`.